# LightSwitch HTML Client (VS2013 Update 4) - how to hide column programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Example: we have a VisualCollection of Customers, Customer has 3 fields of ID, Name, and FavoriteFood, all bound to columns in the table, but at runtime we might need to hide the FavoriteFood column based on the result of some other logic.

I've been able to do a _postRender on the column (like FavoriteFood_postRender) or even on the row template (RowTemplate1_postRender) and toggle isVisible = false for the contentItem to get the particular table cells (td elements) to not display, but in both cases, the table header (th) cell is still present.

The hacky workaround is to do something like $('th:nth-child(3),td:nth-child(3)').hide() although you'd need to do this sufficiently late enough to actually work (the table's postRender happens while the collection is still empty, for instance, and the th elements are present, but the td ones aren't yet, so you could do the th hide there, but you'd then need to contentItem.dataBind to do N different hide's on the td cells, which is kind of ugly), but I'm trying to find out if there's a way of hiding a column via the content items instead since they all have isVisible and it seems like the Right Way of hiding things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others that run across this, I couldn't figure out the programmatic approach using isVisible and similar LightSwitch model properties, so did something basically like the question states.  I think I could have combined each pair into 1 line with "td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)" but this was good enough for me.

```
.hideColumn4               td:nth-child(4)   { display:none !important; } 
.hideColumn4               th:nth-child(4)   { display:none !important; } 

.hideColumn5               td:nth-child(5)   { display:none !important; } 
.hideColumn5               th:nth-child(5)   { display:none !important; } 

.hideColumn6               td:nth-child(6)   { display:none !important; } 
.hideColumn6               th:nth-child(6)   { display:none !important; }
```

Then in the table's postRender, after figuring out which ones to hide, I do something like:

```
if (conditionForHidingColumn4) {
    $(element).addClass('hideColumn4');
}
```

By doing it in the table's postRender, I can make sure I add those classes to just the table I want and not affect any other tables.